# Can't use Self hosted SonarQube on Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently trying to integrate SonarQube into my CI/CD pipeline. But I ran into an error.
When setting up I used my own domain to go to my SonarQube instance. For this thread I will use this:
`sonar.mydomain.com` as my host. This host has a CNAME Record to another domain that uses an IPv6 address.
When I use this domain I get this error: `ENOTFOUND` and if I use the IPv6 address I get this error: `ENETUNREACH`. Right now I have used the IPv4 address, but this will regularly change.

So my question now is this. Why is this happening and how (if possible) can you solve it.

If further details are needed please leave a comment.

EDIT:

I forgot to add something. I have tested my domain with curl and it said that it couldn't resolve my domain.

Solution:

I figured something out. In my situation, I didn't use a DDNS provider for my domain name. So the IP address wouldn't be reachable (Also due to it being IPv6 only). I fixed it by using DuckDNS for my DDNS Provider.

Thanks to all the people that helped me resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent? Is your SonarQube server's DNS publicly accessible?

Comment: The domain is registered and publicly available. I believe I am using the Hosted agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I have tested my domain with curl and it said that it couldn't resolve my domain.

It seems that there is something wrong with your domain, please contact IT depart to resolve it.

In addition, you could [identify the possible IP ranges for Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking) and then allow them.

Also, if your organization is secured with a firewall or proxy server, you need to [add certain IP addresses and domain URLs to the Allow list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops).

BTW, [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) don't support IPV6 as this [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ipv6-on-azure-pipelines/923987) earlier reported. Thus we suggest that you use IPV4 address.